# Merge or combine two columns in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I am not sure if my title is correct one, but here is the deal:

I want to make a matrix visualization in Power Bi Desktop. I have fields: ARTICLE_ID and ARTICLE_NAME.
I would like to have both those fields in COLUMNS position in matrix data view. And I need them to be in one row, no need to drill down... because it is one and the same thing...
I need to have ARTICLE_ID and ARTICLE_NAME as two separate columns on the same level. without drilling. And also, I dont want to use concatenation or merging into some third column. is that possible? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** I started with this sample data.

[image: Data]

**2)** I created a matrix and configured it as shown in the image below.

[image: Matrix]

**3)** I clicked the forked arrows to show all levels.

[image: Drill down]

[image: After drill down]

**4)** In the Rows section of the formatting pane, I turned off "Stepped layout".

[image: Stepped layout]

**5)** In the Subtotals section, I turned off "Row subtotals".

[image: Subtotals]

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but I think it is the closest I can come up with since you don't want to concatenate the columns together.

Comment: just curious, how did you enable dark mode in PowerBi, As of now (8/2022) it's not available yet. or is it just a high-contrast theme?

Comment: @A5H1Q - I honestly don't remember doing anything; that is just how PBI looked for me back then.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Is your Power BI Desktop in the dark mode now?  I searched many forums and threads to find a solution to switch to a dark theme, but no results so far :(

Comment: @A5H1Q No, not recently. I guess they just changed the look of it at some point. Hopefully they do implement a dark mode.

Answer (score 1):

If they are from the same table then just drag and drop them into the columns.

The way a matrix works from my understanding in PowerBI is;

Rows are just the headings/categories of the values.
You might need to also go into the format tab, values, and make sure **show on rows** is on.

[image]

For example, let's say our value headings are rainy days and sunny days.
Your columns are months.
The rows will be the 2 categories.
The values will be the values.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I am looking for. I have two fields (columns returned by a query: ARTICLE_ID and ARTICLE_NAME). They are supposed to be in one row, like: ID ... - .... NAME so no drilling is necessary.... now I have one row (top level) ARTICLE_ID and if I click on the button to go down one level, I get the name of the ARTICLE and the values get repeated twice... that looks weird... is there a way to combine the two to be displayed in one row without actual concatenation in query?

Comment: Provide some pictures. Hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

As concatenation and "&" does not work in Power BI directquery you can use the below one:

**[New_column_name] = if((table_name[column_name]="A" && table_name[column_name]="B"),"AB","NA")**

Thanks,
Sachin Kashyap